# Recoil of an atom absorbing a photon

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, atomic-physics, quantum-optics

I am reading the article named *[Manipulating Atoms with Photons](http://www.phys.ens.fr/%7Edalibard/publi2/New-Physics.pdf)* by Claude Cohen-Tannoudji and Jean Dalibard. On page no. 16, the following is said.

> Consider the atom in its ground state $g$ and its center of mass initially at rest;
> suppose that a photon with wave vector $\textbf{k}$ is sent on this atom. If the atom absorbs the photon, it jumps to the excited state and it recoils with the momentum $\hbar\textbf{k}$.

**My confusion**

I am confused about the direction of the recoil momentum.

To be specific, let's say the photon's wave vector is $\textbf{k} = k\hat{x}$, where $\hat{x}$ is the unit vector. If the atom absorbs the corresponding momentum $\textbf{p}_\text{photon} \equiv \hbar\textbf{k} = \hbar k \hat{x}$, then I think the recoil momentum is
$\textbf{p}_\text{recoil} = -\hbar\textbf{k} = -\hbar k \hat{x}$, so that the momentum of the atom is conserved before (it is $0$) and after the absorption ($\textbf{p}_\text{photon} + \textbf{p}_\text{recoil} = 0$). What am I missing here?

Comment: > *"then I think the recoil momentum is ... $-\hbar\mathbf k$"* That makes no sense. The photon is absorbed, so its momentum lives on as momentum of the atom. There is always momentum $\hbar \mathbf k$. No body here has momentum $-\hbar\mathbf k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am reading the article named *[Manipulating Atoms with Photons][1]* by Claude Cohen-Tannoudji and Jean Dalibard. On page no. 16, the following is said.
>
> > Consider the atom in its ground state $g$ and its center of mass initially at rest;
> > suppose that a photon with wave vector $\textbf{k}$ is sent on this atom. If the atom absorbs the photon, it jumps to the excited state and it recoils with the momentum $\hbar\textbf{k}$.
>
> I am confused about the direction of the recoil momentum.
> To be specific, let's say the photon's wave vector is $\textbf{k} = k\hat{x}$, where $\hat{x}$ is the unit vector. If the atom absorbs the corresponding momentum $\textbf{p}_\text{photon} \equiv \hbar\textbf{k} = \hbar k \hat{x}$,

> ...then I think the recoil momentum is
> $\textbf{p}_\text{recoil} = -\hbar\textbf{k} = -\hbar k \hat{x}$

No, that is wrong. You should have:
$$
\textbf{p}_\text{recoil} = \textbf{p}_\text{photon}=\hbar\textbf{k}
$$

The total initial momentum is:
$$
0\;+\; \hbar\textbf{k}\;,
$$
where $0$ is the initial momentum of the atom and $\hbar\textbf{k}$ is the initial momentum of the photon.

The total final momentum is:
$$
\hbar\textbf{k}\;+\; 0\;,
$$
where $\hbar\textbf{k}$ is the final momentum of the atom and $0$ is the final momentum of the photon.

> What am I missing here?

Conservation of momentum applies to the total/isolated system of atom plus photon:
$$
\textbf{P}_\text{total} = \textbf{p}_\text{atom} + \textbf{p}_\text{photon}
$$

It is only $\textbf{P}_\text{total}$ that is necessarily conserved. Since $\textbf{P}_\text{total}$ started off as $\hbar\textbf{k}$ it must alway remain at that value regardless of how you apportion it between atom and photon.